# Hosting DigitalGlobe stereo imagery on GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, stereo-imagery, maxar-digitalglobe

I have a pretty fresh install of the latest Boundless OpenGeo stack (v4.5).  I have a requirement to host some stereo satellite imagery.  I'm using the sample imagery over China provided by DigitalGlobe (https://www.digitalglobe.com/product-samples).  The .zip file is quite large and contains a directory for panchromatic imagery, one for multispectral imagery, and a GIS_FILES directory that seems to just contain various footprint shapefiles.  Each of the imagery directories contain many supporting files: .ATT, .EPH, .GEO, .IMD, .RPB, .STE, .TIL...  DigitalGlobe has an Imagery Support Data Document (https://www.digitalglobe.com/sites/default/files/ISD_External.pdf) that explains the information in each file.  They all seem to provide information about the image pairs, overlaps, etc.

I'm confused how to properly host this data in GeoServer.

Should the two GeoTIFFs be added to independent stores in GeoServer?

Is there some other sort of mechanism that keeps the two images together or contains the metadata in the DG provided files?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the data? Would you prefer to deal with each image separately, or does an Image Mosaic (http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/image_mosaic_plugin/imagemosaic.html) make more sense for your needs? Also, is there any significance for your postgis tag? Do you have it and want to use it for something particular? Do you need the footprints?

Comment: The images will likely be used in a 3rd party app, so we won't be doing any mosaicing. I tagged postgis because it's bundled with OpenGeo and backs GeoServer.  Some people apparently load imagery directly into the db, point GeoServer to the table, and let gdal work its magic. I wasn't sure if the tag was relevant or not, but I decided to include it. The real confusion is just, if I want to obtain the pair of images, do I have to independently find each one via CSW? Or is there some other built in mechanism to have a relationship between the two?

Comment: I think you need to edit the question, and try to get to a single question. At the moment, you're asking for a data management strategy without saying why. Saying what the third party application is might help.